# Laravel 5 response()->json always returns an array?

Tags: php, json, eloquent, laravel-5

Is there any way to stop laravel always returning an array, regardless if there is only a single element? I've checked the docs and come up short. It's fine if thats just the way it is of course, just seems a little silly, as you wouldn't post an array to an endpoint, if there was only one element!

Return payload for sanity sake:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2015-05-22 15:41:24",
        "updated_at": "2015-05-22 15:41:24",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "closed_loop_interaction_type_id": 1,
        "interaction_note": "Test Interaction note",
        "closed_loop_processes_id": 1,
        "interaction_type": {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2015-05-22 15:41:24",
            "updated_at": "2015-05-22 15:41:24",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "type": 0,
            "method": "Phone Call (mobile)"
        }
    }
]
```

That's one object, but sent back as an array of 1. Is there a way to stop this? Is it the way I'm populating models?

```
$query = ClosedLoopInteraction::with('interactionType');
// Construct a list of headers
$headers = \HeaderHelper::generatePaginationHeader($page, $query, 'closedloop', $limit);
\QueryHelper::handleQueryFiltering(
    $query, ['limit'=> $limit, 'page' => $page]);
$response = response()->json($query->get(), \ApiResponse::$STATUS_OK);
// Add the constructed headers to the response
\HeaderHelper::addHeadersToResponse($response, $headers);
return $response;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Query [first()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_first) method rather than the [get()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) method

Answer (score 1):

Well, Laravel, from behind, is using `json_encode` in order to return the JSON you are seeing, having this on hand, you can know that when you pass an array, no matter the length, even `length === 1`, you will get an output as an array, because thats the way `json_encode` works, so you should do as @Mark Baker says, and modify the following line:

```
$response = response()->json($query->get(), \ApiResponse::$STATUS_OK);
```

To:

```
$response = response()->json($query->first(), \ApiResponse::$STATUS_OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Looking at your code you are returning a list of models. If thats the case you should also return an array, be it empty, single or many models. That way the return type is always the same and easier to process. However if you viewing a specific model, editing or something, use the method `first()` suggested by another answer.